# How do I find the location of a svn repository?

Tags: svn, working-copy, svn-repository

I have all the source files in my "local" directory. I do `svn up` and `svn ci` to down- and up-load code from and to repository, respectively.

Now I have realized that there is one directory in the repository for which I did not make a local copy. So, I need to do two things:

1. Find out where repository is located (I am quite sure it is somewhere in the file system, not URL).
2. I need to create a local copy of this directory.

How can it be done? At the moment I am more interested in the first step. I need to know where the repository is located since I do not really know what the name of the subdirectory that I need to copy is (but if I see the names I might guess).

Comment: By a local directory you mean a working copy, am I right?

Comment: @bahrep, yes, I mean the copy that I modify and then submit to the server.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`svn info` inside repository and check "Repository root" string